# converting JSON array in javascript object

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am trying to print `classkey` and `status` from `myJson` array. I have converted `myJSON` into an object. But I am unable to print `classkey` and `status`. In this code `myJSON` is auto generated and one dot in `godaddy.com` as well.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        var myJSON = '{"godaddy.com":{"classkey":"domcno","status":"available"}}';
        var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
        document.write(myObj.hostdady.com[1].classkey);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: More or like [0] ?

Answer (score 0):

Use square bracket notation to escape invalid variable name

```
document.write(myObj['godaddy.com'].classkey)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing your string correctly, but you are making a mistake when you go to print the selected property.

When you go to write the selected property you are selecting a property that does not exist, `hostdady.com` instead of `godaddy.com`

```
 document.write(myObj.hostdady.com[1].classkey);
```

But, even if you changed that to `myObj.godaddy.com[1].classkey` you would still run into problems because of the `.` between `godaddy` and `com`. The browser will interpret this as the `com` property of `godaddy`.

Instead, to access the godaddy.com property, you would need to write:

```
myObj['godaddy.com']
```

And, that property does not hold an array, so you do not need the `[0]` instead just look for the classkey as any other property:

```
document.write(myObj["godaddy.com"].classkey);
```

```html
            <html>
            <head>
            <script>
            var myJSON = '{"godaddy.com":{"classkey":"domcno","status":"available"}}';
            var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
            document.write(myObj["godaddy.com"].classkey);
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <p></p>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.

```js
var myJSON = '{"godaddy.com":{"classkey":"domcno","status":"available"}}';

var myObj =JSON.parse(myJSON);

var classKey = myObj["godaddy.com"].classkey ;

document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML = classKey;
```

```html
<p id="dynamic"></p>
```

For More help [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

**Some Observations :**

- `myJSON` is not an `JSON object`. It is a `JSON String.`
- Use `JSON.parse` to convert `JSON String` into `JSON Object`.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myJSON = '{"godaddy.com":{"classkey":"domcno","status":"available"}}';
var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
for(var i in myObj) {
document.getElementById("classkey").innerHTML = myObj[i].classkey;
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = myObj[i].status;
}
```

```html
<p id="classkey"></p>
<p id="status"></p>
```